# Handle navigation between several view in a WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, architecture, view

I've done several WPF application(not using MVVM) in the past and I had always to implement my own system of navigation between view(instantiate the view once, and then load in a container component, with refreshing required components of my view).

It works, but:

- It's always custom, so if a new developer comes he has to learn of it how it works
- I'm pretty sure that It's not the most optimized(most of things haven't been done in background worker, ...)
- It's a time loss

So I was wondering if there is an official way to handle this ? I don't exactly how, but I was thinking to a navigation component, which can act a little like a tab panel, or a little like the MVC framework in asp.net, we can call a specified controller for an action and some parameters.

Maybe deactiviting bindings when they aren't in the current view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use DataTemplates/Styles to customize content of your control ( not only apearance, but data, cause that what you're asking for I presume)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx

You can have one Host control and at runtime change its appearance based on events/ states.

Like an example can have a look here:
http://code.google.com/p/svnradar/ how this program manages a appearance of Group and Flat view of repository information.

Another example:
Podder of Josh Smith

http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2008/03/05/podder-v2-has-been-released/

Hope this helps.

Comment: It doesn't really tell me if there is a standard way to manage the navigation between interfaces. Like I said, I've already build some application with custom navigation system(which use event, ...), but it's not what I want

Comment: The " standart way" is using templates and bind them at runtime, that is a point.

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested by [Lakana](http://lakana.codeplex.com), a lightweight (but powerful) framework that can handle for you all the navigation concerns !

Riana